# MYSQL, created a user-defined-function for date|datetime inserts, but it doesn't work

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I built a small MySQL user-defined-function which I thought would sanity check a date|datetime value before copying it between rows.

This what I came up with:

```
drop function safe_date;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION safe_date(input varchar (255))
RETURNS datetime
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare output datetime;

    if ((SELECT WEEK(input) IS NOT NULL AS valid) > 0) then
       set output= input;
    else 
       set output = NULL;
    END IF;
return output;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

It seems to work when I test it:

```
mysql> select safe_date(0);
+--------------+
| safe_date(0) |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select safe_date('');
+---------------+
| safe_date('') |
+---------------+
| NULL          |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select safe_date('2012-05-');
+-----------------------+
| safe_date('2012-05-') |
+-----------------------+
| NULL                  |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select safe_date('2012-05-05');
+-------------------------+
| safe_date('2012-05-05') |
+-------------------------+
| 2012-05-05 00:00:00     |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

But when I try to catch an in-valid datetime in an insert, I get an error:

```
mysql> show create table test;
+-------+--------------------------------
| Table | Create Table                   
+-------+--------------------------------
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+--------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(1,safe_date('2012-05-05'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values(2,safe_date('2012-05-'));
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2012-05-'
mysql>
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I am tripping over?

> What version of mysql are you using? I tried on mysql 5.7 and it works without error. Also what sql mode you have? show session variables like 'sql_mode%'

Here is some system information:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES like 'version';
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| version       | 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-log |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show session variables like 'sql_mode%';
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? I tried on mysql 5.7 and it works without error. Also what sql mode you have?  

show session variables like 'sql_mode%'

Comment: Hi, I added reply to original post

Comment: I tried your sql mode, still works. I have 5.7.20

Comment: what SELECT 2 AS c1, safe_date('2012-05-') AS c2  returns?

Comment: Returns:

 c1 =2   c2 =NULL

Answer (score 0):

After revisiting this problem I found a solution.

It is related to sql_mode, specifically **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES** is the setting which causes ERROR 1292 in my setup.

I added this line to **mysqld.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

.. that's basically all current settings minus **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES**

Restart mysqld, and now my custom function works, and is reboot safe.